# Ejecting a device connected via Android File Transfer

Tags: internal-storage, file-transfer, usb-connection-mode

I recently upgraded from a device running Android 2.3 to 4.2. On my 2.3 device, I could use USB Connection Mode to automatically mount the device on OSX. When I first connected my 4.2 device, I was surprised when I was prompted to install Android File Transfer instead. Is it safe to disconnect by simply removing it from the USB cable?